# SQL: Group By and create a new json column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  name  |                result             |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1    | Maria  |    {type: download, status: pass} |
| 1    | Maria  |    {type: login, status: fail}    |
| 2    | Tony   |    {type: download, status: fail} |
| 3    | Kate   |    {type: download, status: pass} |
| 3    | Kate   |    {type: login, status: pass}    |
| 3    | Kate   |    {type: logout, status: pass}   |
| 4    | Tom    |    {type: download, status: pass} |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to try to get this but not sure that it possible:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  name  |  download |           action            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | Maria  |    pass   |      {login: fail}          |
| 2    | Tony   |    fail   |                             |
| 3    | Kate   |    pass   | {login: pass, logout: pass} |
| 4    | Tom    |    pass   |                             |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I found way to create a new simple column:

```
SELECT id, name
       results.download AS download
FROM
(
    SELECT id, name jsonb_agg(result) AS results
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY id, name
) AS r
ORDER BY id, name;
```

but also I want to move login and logout field to action column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is not exactly as you want but we have the right information in the right place.

> ```
> create table my_table (
> id int,
> name varchar(10),
> result text
> );
> insert into my_table values
> (1,'Maria','{ "type": "download", "status": "pass"}'),
> (1,'Maria','{ "type": "login", "status": "fail"}'),
> (2,'Tony','{ "type": "download", "status": "fail"}'),
> (3,'Kate','{ "type": "download", "status": "pass"}'),
> (3,'Kate','{ "type": "login", "status": "pass"}'),
> (3,'Kate','{ "type": "logout", "status": "pass"}'),
> (4,'Tom','{ "type": "download", "status": "pass"}');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

7 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT id, name
>        results.download AS download
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT id, name jsonb_agg(result) AS results
>         FROM my_table
>         GROUP BY id, name
> ) AS r
> ORDER BY id, name;
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
> ```

LINE 2:        results.download AS download
^

> 

> ```
> select
>   id,
>   name,
>   result::json->'type' AS type,
>   result::json->'status' AS status
> FROM my_table
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | type       | status
> -: | :---- | :--------- | :-----
>  1 | Maria | "download" | "pass"
>  1 | Maria | "login"    | "fail"
>  2 | Tony  | "download" | "fail"
>  3 | Kate  | "download" | "pass"
>  3 | Kate  | "login"    | "pass"
>  3 | Kate  | "logout"   | "pass"
>  4 | Tom   | "download" | "pass"
> ```

> ```
> with cte as
> (select 
>   id,
>   name,
>   case when cast(result::json->'type' as text) = '"download"' 
>     then cast(result::json->'status' as text) end as "download" ,
>   case when cast(result::json->'type' as text)  in ('"login"','"logout"') 
>   then concat(result::json->'type',': ',result::json->'status') end as "action"
> from my_table)
> select 
>   id, 
>   name,
>   max(download),
>   string_agg(action,', ') "action"
> from cte
> group by
>   id, 
>   name
> order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | max    | action                           
> -: | :---- | :----- | :--------------------------------
>  1 | Maria | "pass" | "login": "fail"                  
>  2 | Tony  | "fail" | null                             
>  3 | Kate  | "pass" | "login": "pass", "logout": "pass"
>  4 | Tom   | "pass" | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8fec5f97a777ed0e701cb12d96f8eac3)*

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the downloads and the "other" items into two separate columns:

```
with data as (
  select id, 
         name, 
         jsonb_object_agg('download', result ->> 'status') filter (where result ->> 'type' = 'download') as download,
         jsonb_object_agg(result ->> 'type', result ->> 'status') filter (where result ->> 'type' <> 'download') as result
  from my_table
  group by id, name
)
select id, name,
       download ->> 'download' as download,
       result
from data;
```

The CTE returns this:

```
id | name  | download             | results                            
---+-------+----------------------+------------------------------------
 1 | Maria | {"download": "pass"} | {"login": "fail"}                  
 2 | Tony  | {"download": "fail"} |                                    
 3 | Kate  | {"download": "pass"} | {"login": "pass", "logout": "pass"}
 4 | Tom   | {"download": "pass"} |
```

And the final then just extracts the value for the `download` key.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f20191a073aff2acce690644ee081d3)